# How to mark messages from Field Trip as read?

Tags: geolocation

Maybe it's just me, but how does one mark messages as being read in Field Trip?  I was using it today and they same landmark popped up multiple times through out the day.  I can't seem to find a way to mark it as being read so that it'll no longer pop up as I pass it.